# Convert GeoJSON to TopoJSON

Tags: convert, geojson, topojson

How can [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) data to [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki) be converted?

TopoJSON files are often smaller than GeoJSON and the conversion allows you to incrementally simplify a dataset, if you wish.

Comment: Step 3: Convert the data: topojson -o output_file.json input_file.json not working!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `topojson -o output_file.json input_file.json` works for me under 1.1.0 and 1.4.0. Perhaps you can ask a formal question on here with more info on the problem you're having? Cheers!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Glad you asked, oh handsome OP.

### Install `topojson`

From the command line (Mac OSX 10.8, assumes [homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed):

```
brew install node.js
npm install -g topojson
```

### Convert The Data

```
topojson -o output.json input.json
```

Comment: OP is handsome, but needs to update his answer.

Answer (score 10):

The function to create a topojson from a geojson in [topojson](https://github.com/topojson/topojson) has been moved to [geo2topo](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-server/blob/master/README.md#geo2topo)

```
npm install topojson-server -g
geo2topo input.geojson > output.topojson
```

Comment: For me this does not work. I am getting a `not recognized` error when trying to run `geo2topo` after running `npm install topojson-server`

Comment: Updated the answer to include the global flag `-g` try it now @JoeBe

Comment: thanks. This worked perfectly. It would be great if you could tell me what the difference is here? Why do I need a global flag for this whereas for other libraries I installed until now this was not necessary? What happens behind the hood?

Comment: Install globally if you are using a package as a command line tool and locally if it only needs to be accessible from scripts in an app https://stackoverflow.com/a/8951576/441878

Answer (score 3):

I ported the TopoJSON code from JavaScript to Python, following the exact same format Mike uses in his library (along with his +300 tests).

If you feel better with Python, just install the library by running:

```bsh
pip install pytopojson
```

And then run:

```bsh
python geo2topo.py geojson_file
```

You can also use a quantization parameter. Just use the `-h` argument to see how it works.

Let me know if this was helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found pretty good **online tool for simplifying geospatial data** (including GeoJSON) and export to various formats (including TopoJSON) at https://geoprocessing.online/tool/simplify-polygons/. You can upload the GeoJSON, set simplification level and export to TopoJSON. For more information on data size reduction, see this article: https://kb.geoczech.org/knowledge-base/how-to-reduce-size-of-vector-data/