Simplify by removing overlapping lineparts in adjacent polygon features
I am looking for a way of simplifying my GeoJSON file by removing overlapping lineparts between adjacent polygons.
I have a GeoJSON file with polygons of cadastral parcels which, by definition, are all adjacent polygons. Therefore almost every line is defined twice in both adjacent polygons.

Is there a way to remove one of every two overlapping lineparts?
A consequence will probably be that many of the polygons no longer form a closed loop anymore, or even become MultiLineStrings. That would be no problem for my purpose. My only objective is to visualize the parcel lines. There is no need to identify them, analyse them or keep them in their original form. As long as each line part can be visualised on a screen.
I tried Mapshaper, but that resulted in changing lines, removing edges and corners, but no removal of double defined line parts.
GeoJSON file attached
Upon trying the Planar Graph suggestion created a parcel block of 16 adjacent parcels and tried to calculate a optimal way of defining these in a GeoJSON format.

Original GeoJSON
Polygon I: A1 - A2 - B2 - B1 - A1
Each other polygon defined by 5 lat, lon coordinates
16 x 5 = 80 coordinates in total
Filesize: 4.357 bytes
Manually Simplified
Polygon I: A1 - A2 - B2 - B1 - A1
Same for the entire top row: 5 coordinates for polygon I, II, III, IV
First row: 4 x 5 = 20 coordinates in total
Polygon V: B1 - C1 - C2
Same for polygon VI and VI: 3 coordinates
Polygon VIII: B4 - C4 - C5 - B5
Second row: 3 x 3 = 9 + 4 = 13 coordinates in total
Third and fourth row similar. 3 x 13 = 39 coordinates
All together: 20 + 39 = 59 coordinates instead of 80
OpenJump - Planar Graph
4 Linestrings with 3 coordinates = 12
32 LineStrings with 2 coordinates = 64
All together: 76 coordinates
Filesize: 5.557 bytes (25% larger that the original GeoJSON file)
The objective is to reduce file size in GeoJSON format. My source file holds 8 million parcels and is 5Gb and the hosting price is largely determined by file size.
Is there a tool in the GIS world that could optimize the GeoJSON file to have the least number of coordinates possible and therefore the smallest possible file size.
No other information like feature id or any attribute is needed for my purpose. Just the MultiLineStrings or Polygons to draw the lines on the screen.

You probably want to convert to topojson : https://github.com/topojson/topojson (for converting : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45138/convert-geojson-to-topojson)

What gis software are you using

I used mapshaper to simplify and Qgis to remove overlap and ogr2ogr. So far I could not find a possibility to remove these double line parts.
The final output should be a GeoJSON file

What software can you use? In JS there is library TopoJSON (https://unpkg.com/topojson@3) which can easily achieve what you want.

@J.R Ultimately I need to upload a GeoJSON to host my parcels. Would converting from GeoJSON tot topojson allow my to reduce file size and than convert back to GeoJSON while keeping the reduces file size?

OpenJUMP Plus http://openjump.org/ has a Create Planar Graph tool. The edge layer of the generated graph contains line segments without duplicates.
Source data

Create the graph

The edges of the generated graph have no duplicates


I tried the Plana Graph suggestion. But that didn't give an optimal result, because Planar Graph creates LineStrings instead of MultiLineStrings. See my dictional edit to the first post.

The result is not optimal when it comes to filesize but I think it meets the description in the question "I am looking for a way of simplifying my GeoJSON file by removing overlapping lineparts between adjacent polygons".

You absolutely right. I will reformulate the question and create a new posting
